# ReferenceError include is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

```
 var number= include('dir1/dir2/SqlQueryMailNotification.js');
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: include is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\metrix\source-code\MeTRIX_Next Gen Server\lib\notificationMail.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\metrix\source-code\MeTRIX_Next Gen Server\server.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

Comment: I think you need to add a basic description in your question. That is why some people downvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

include() is neither a valid ES6 nor a valid Node.js function. You have to do:

```
var number = require('dir1/dir2/SqlQueryMailNotification.js');
```